# Installing a downloaded extension with a composer

Tags: magento2, composer

I am new to M2 and don't exactly know much about composer.

I am able to install extensions from GitHub or Magento store with composer just fine.

But I don't know what to do with extensions where "component name" is not provided. I want to be able to later easily update it like you can with composer.

So how do I install a downloaded extension via composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You need extensions name, just open `registration.php` file directly in extension folder. There should be something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magento_Captcha',
    __DIR__
);
```

Magento_Captcha is extension name.

If you want enable new extension installed via composer run:
composer update  composer install (depends)
`php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Captcha`
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

EDIT:
To add new repo to composer use:
`composer require username/project`
For example https://github.com/weprovide/magento2-module-disablevisitorlog
`compsoer require weprovide/magento2-module-disablevisitorlog`

Comment: So what do I type in `composer require `?

Comment: I see, I just edited my post

Comment: for this to work, it would require for the extension to be on the github, right?

Comment: in composer.json You can see which repos you can use. There is section "repositories". You can easly add different. Anyway you can use also https://packagist.org/ to check which packages are public. Following example from post: https://packagist.org/packages/weprovide/magento2-module-disablevisitorlog

Comment: ah, I see, so I should be also be able to add a local path there?

Comment: local path? Can you explain me what You exactly want to do? You want to create new module and use it via composer?

Comment: Well, I have the module downloaded as a .zip file and I want to install it with a composer

Comment: Oh. It wont work like that. At first you should check is there (in zip) composer.json file. Then check `name` inside and use this name in composer require. If there is no composer.json or you have no access to repo (may be private), you should install this extension in app/code or create own repo fg. on github and deploy this extension there - using own repos name